# Executar um java Jar pelo Delphi

Tags: java, delphi, linha-de-comando

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de executar um jar pelo Delphi e dar comandos a ele como se fosse uma linha de comando.

A verdade é que tenho uma aplicação em java que não tenho mais acesso ao código e ela é limitada a dois comandos via console, eu gostaria de criar uma aplicação em delphi que pudesse por uma interface gráfica controlar esse jar e dar comandos a eles, então invés do usuário digitar os comandos, ele clicaria em botões e o delphi faria o resto.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Pelo menos até o Delphi 7 isso era feito usando a API do Windows. Se quiser apenas lançar o outro aplicativo é fácil. Se quiser esperar ele terminar é mais chato e se quiser ler as saídas dele é preciso ir para o lado sombrio da força. Especifique a sua versão do Delphi e o que você precisa obter do outro programa. Pode ir lendo isto enquanto isso: delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/executeprogram.htm

Comment: Exatamente @Caffé, eu quero executar e ler as saídas deles e dar entradas nele também, no stack overflow gringo me falaram de algo sobre o CreateProcess e sobre pipes mas eu não entendi muito bem como funciona e se vai dar certo para o meu caso, quanto a versão do Delphi eu tenho aqui disponível a 2009 e a XE5

Comment: De uma forma muito simples, você pode utilizar `java seuJar.jar parametros > .\output.txt` e daí a saída do console vai ser salva no arquivo informado.

Comment: O @Caputo está correto se você não precisa obter as saídas ao passo que elas são entregues. Outrosim, eu tenho um código pronto que adaptei de um artigo da internet que não encontro mais. Vou ver se trago amanhã para postar aqui. Agora, quanto a ficar enviando entradas para um aplicativo em execução a solução pode ser bem complexa e depende de muita coisa: você passa valores apenas ao disparar o programa? (daí seria simples). Você quer passar valores durante a execução do programa? Que tipo de valores são e como o programa espera obter estes valores?

Comment: Então @Caffé, a aplicação que tenho ela tem apenas 2 comandos, listar e sair, eu precisaria abrir essa aplicação pelo delphi e pelo mesmo dar esses comandos e no caso do listar eu pegaria as informações que ele retornaria.

Comment: @brunodotcom Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: @qmechanik Obrigado pelas respostas, na verdade ainda não tive tempo de implantar a ideia de vocês, mas aparentemente vai resolver. A hora que eu conseguir implantar eu já dou a resposta aqui.

Answer (score 4):

Supondo que seu aplicativo **jar** se chame *meuApp.jar* você pode fazer da seguinte forma

no Delphi vc executa o comando com WinExec por exemplo, ou ShellExecute

```
WinExec('java c:\path\para\meuApp.jar listar >> .\resultadoLista.txt', SW_HIDE);
```

ou

```
ShellExecute(handle,'open',PChar('java'), 
  'c:\path\para\meuApp.jar listar >> .\resultadoLista.txt','',SW_HIDE)
```

Daí, depois no delphi vc pode carregar o resultado usando um memo ou stringlist por exemplo:

```
StringList.LoadFromFile('.\resultadoLista.txt')
```

Answer (score 3):

Além dos modos [**citados pelo Caputo**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58444/6454), é possível usar a função [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) para executar o *jar*, salvar num arquivo e carregá-lo num [`TStringList`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TStringList). Algo semelhante a isto:

```pascal
function ExecutarComando(Comando: string): TStringList;
var
 SE: TShellExecuteInfo;
 ExitCode: DWORD;
begin
 Result := TStringList.Create;
 FillChar(SE, SizeOf(SE), 0);
 SE.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
 SE.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
 SE.Wnd := Application.Handle;
 SE.lpFile := 'cmd.exe';
 SE.lpParameters :=  pchar('/C' + Comando + ' > output.txt');
 SE.nShow := SW_HIDE;

 if ShellExecuteEx(@SE) then begin
   repeat
     Application.ProcessMessages;
     GetExitCodeProcess(SE.hProcess, ExitCode);
   until (ExitCode <> STILL_ACTIVE) or Application.Terminated;
     Result.LoadFromFile('output.txt');
 end else
     RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Para utilizar:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.Lines := ExecutarComando('java arquivo.jar listar');
end;
```

O método acima é funcional, porém não é o ideal, um outro modo mais *elegante* de fazer isto é criar o processo com a função [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), e redirecionar a saída para um [*Buffer*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_%28ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29) com a função [`CreatePipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), basicamente.

[Essa página](http://www.delphidabbler.com/tips/61) mostra um exemplo de como fazer isto.

```pascal
function GetDosOutput(CMD: string; Diretorio: string = 'C:\'): string;
var
  SA: TSecurityAttributes;
  SI: TStartupInfo;
  PI: TProcessInformation;
  StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite: THandle;
  Handle, WasOK: Boolean;
  Buffer: array[0..255] of AnsiChar;
  BytesRead: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := '';
  SA.nLength := SizeOf(SA);
  SA.bInheritHandle := True;
  SA.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
  CreatePipe(StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite, @SA, 0);

  try
     FillChar(SI, SizeOf(SI), 0);
     SI.cb := SizeOf(SI);
     SI.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
     SI.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
     SI.hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
     SI.hStdOutput := StdOutPipeWrite;
     SI.hStdError := StdOutPipeWrite;

     Handle := CreateProcess(nil, PChar('cmd.exe /C ' + CMD), nil, nil, True,
     0, nil, pchar(Diretorio), SI, PI);
     CloseHandle(StdOutPipeWrite);
     if Handle then
       try
         repeat
           WasOK := ReadFile(StdOutPipeRead, Buffer, 255, BytesRead, nil);
           if BytesRead > 0 then begin
             Buffer[BytesRead] := #0;
             Result := Result + String(Buffer);
           end;
         until not WasOK or (BytesRead = 0);
        WaitForSingleObject(PI.hProcess, INFINITE);
       finally
         CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
         CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
       end;
   finally
     CloseHandle(StdOutPipeRead);
   end;
end;
```

Para utilizar:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
// O segundo argumento é opcional, por padrão o comando executa em C:\
Memo1.Text := GetDosOutput('java arquivo.jar listar', 'C:\Dir\'); 
end;
```

Comment: Com relação ao `ShellExecuteEX`, quando a máscara `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` é utilizada, o chamador é responsável por fechar o handle que ele recebeu. No seu caso, você esqueceu de fechar o handle `hProcess`.